# 'div_element' is null or not an object in IE7

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-events

Here I have get one error in JavaScript  `div_element` is null or not an object.
I have given my code below:

```
function showLoading(id) {
div_element = $("div#" + id)[0];
div_element.innerHTML = loading_anim; // Error in this line
}
```

When I am debugging my script but it's working fine in other browsers including IE 8, but it's not working in IE 7. I don't understand what exact issue occur in this script.

Comment: Just a question: Why would you do that if `$('#'+id).html(loading_anim)` would be much more intuitive since you're already using jQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you dont need to put a tag name infront of the jQuery, unless you have other elements with exact **same id** on other elements, in other pages.

Next, your statement `div_element.innerHTML = loading_anim;` is **correct**. So, the only explanation is that, there is no element with that ID, in the DOM.

**Finally,** since you are usign jQuery already, no need to mix up native JS and jQuery to create a dirty looking code.

```
function showLoading(id) {

    div_element = $("#" + id);
    console.log(div_element); //check the console to see if it return any element or not
    div_element.html(loading_anim);

}
```

Comment: i have exact same id for div and li element so i have written   div_element = $("div#" + id); in script

Answer (score 0):

Use `.html()` for jQuery objects. `innerHTML` work for *dom* objects, they wont work for jQuery objects.

```
function showLoading(id) {
    div_element = $("div#" + id);
    $(div_element).html(loading_anim); // Provided `loading_anim` is valid html element
}
```

Comment: Why would you first extract the DOM element and then convert it to a jQuery object again?

Comment: i get undefined value when i alert div_element in IE-7  and in other browser i get div element object.so i think problem in second line $("div#" + id)[0];

Comment: well , I have have updated the answer. it should be `$("div#" + id)` actually.

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't select anything with your jquery selector (line 2)

try to display

- id
- "div#" + id
- $("div#" + id)
- $("div#" + id)[0]

You can use firebug javascript console or a simple alert like this:
alert($("div#" + id)[0]);

And see if you must id or class on your div ( use # or . selector)

Answer (score 0):

I suppose, that nic wants to display some loader GIF animation, I confirm, that nic must use jQuery `.html()` method for DOM objects, and tusar solution works fine on IE6+ browsers. Also (it is obvious but anyway) nic must assign a value to `loading_anim` variable in script, lets say: `var loading_anim = $('#loader').html();` before assigning its value to `div_element`.